# Looking for comprehensive, parsable table of German noun declensions

Tags: resource

I'm looking for a reasonably comprehensive, and "script-parseable", list/table of German nouns with their declensions (the four cases for all applicable forms).  I.e., the desired information for each noun in the list/table would be something like

```
Haus
  S                                         P
N das Haus                                  die Häuser
A das Haus                                  die Häuser
D dem Haus/Hause                            den Häusern
G des Hauses                                der Häuser

Öffentlichkeit
  S                                         P
N die Öffentlichkeit
A die Öffentlichkeit
D die Öffentlichkeit
G die Öffentlichkeit

Leute
  S                                         P
N                                           die    Leute
A                                           die    Leute
D                                           den    Leuten
G                                           der    Leute

Vorsitzender
  F                    M                    P
N -     Vorsitzende    -     Vorsitzender   -      Vorsitzende
A -     Vorsitzende    -     Vorsitzenden   -      Vorsitzende
D -     Vorsitzender   -     Vorsitzendem   -      Vorsitzenden
G -     Vorsitzender   -     Vorsitzenden   -      Vorsitzender

N die   Vorsitzende    der   Vorsitzende    die    Vorsitzenden
A die   Vorsitzende    den   Vorsitzenden   die    Vorsitzenden
D der   Vorsitzenden   dem   Vorsitzenden   den    Vorsitzenden
G der   Vorsitzenden   des   Vorsitzenden   der    Vorsitzenden

N eine  Vorsitzende    ein   Vorsitzender   keine  Vorsitzenden
A eine  Vorsitzende    einen Vorsitzenden   keine  Vorsitzenden
D einer Vorsitzenden   einem Vorsitzenden   keinen Vorsitzenden
G einer Vorsitzenden   eines Vorsitzenden   keiner Vorsitzenden
```

(Some online search tools, such as [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/), offer this information, but, at least the ones I know of, do not make it available for bulk downloads, and prohibit downloading through script-driven queries.)

Comment: Verbs are conjugated and nouns have a declension. There are no conjugated nouns.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can download the German Wiktionary from [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index-bydb.html).

For an example, here's a part of `dewiktionary-20121115-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2` I downloaded a week ago:

```
    <title>Haus</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1119</id>
    <revision>
      <id>2726902</id>
      <parentid>2709434</parentid>
      <timestamp>2012-11-10T22:44:24Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>BetterkBot</username>
        <id>49296</id>
      </contributor>
      <minor />
      <comment>Bot: Form 2</comment>
      <text xml:space="preserve">{{Wort der Woche|46|2006}}
== Haus ({{Sprache|Deutsch}}) ==
{{überarbeiten|Bedeutungen, Synonyme und Unterbegriffe, Referenzen|Deutsch}}
=== {{Wortart|Substantiv|Deutsch}}, {{n}} ===

{{Deutsch Substantiv Übersicht
|Bild 1=Schiller Weimar.jpg|250px|1|[[w:Friedrich von Schiller|Schiller]]-''Haus'' in Weimar
|Bild 2=Auenstein-fachwerk2.jpg|250px|1|ein ''Haus'' in Fachwerkbauweise
|Bild 3=Wiki pogodinskaya izba moscow.jpg|250px|1|aus Holz gebautes ''Haus'' in Russland
|Bild 4=Leamouth riverside building 1.jpg|250px|1|ein ''Haus'' im modernen Baustil
|Nominativ Singular=das Haus
|Nominativ Plural=die Häuser
|Genitiv Singular=des Hauses
|Genitiv Plural=der Häuser
|Dativ Singular=dem Haus&lt;br /&gt;dem Hause
|Dativ Plural=den Häusern
|Akkusativ Singular=das Haus
|Akkusativ Plural=die Häuser
}}
```

I think it won't be hard for you to parse it.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://github.com/gambolputty/german-nouns) is a list of ~ 79,000 German nouns and their grammatical properties compiled from WiktionaryDE.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out institutes of German language and literature studies at universities whether they have such databases. If you're lucky and ask nicely you may even get database access.

In general, I don't think you will find anything which will be served on a silver platter as you want to have it. I would like to find such a thing for Russian as well, but it is just not going to happen. I tried.