# German words database

Tags: pronunciation, vocabulary, inflection

I'm searching any good database about German words (substantives currently, but a more comprehensible database will go down well also), with, almost, the following information:

- Word name: in nomative Singular.
- natural/grammatical genre
- inflections: in plural, dative plural and genitive singular (or n-declination).
- pronunciation: pronunciation and hyphenation with IPA.

Does you know any free database with these characteristics?

canoo.net meet this requirements (except pronunciation), and moreover has some kind of API:

- [Genitive only "es"](http://canoonet.eu/services/InflectionRules/Controller?matchRules=(BesTab%20Genitiv-mit-s-oder-es-1)&entryClass=Cat%20N&lang=de)
- [Plural with umlaut](http://canoonet.eu/services/InflectionRules/Controller?matchRules=(Bes%20Umlaut-im-Plural)&entryClass=Cat%20N&lang=de)

But I haven't seen any description of this API in any point of canoo.net. You can only have access of these lists by means of the web page.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words?rq=1

Comment: Also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/looking-for-comprehensive-parsable-table-of-conjugated-german-nouns

Comment: I should to check wiktionary, because I think it is a very incomplete dictionary, and for my purposes it isn't enough. Moreover, I need a database that can be treated mechanically by means of an algorithm, and I've a little experience processing wikis, and wikis isn't exactly well databases.

Answer (score 8):

The [German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aHauptseite) offers all information you require.

Let's for example take the substantive *dog*. The [Wiktionary entry for dog](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hund) gives us:

> - Word name: *Hund*
> - natural/grammatical genre: *m*
> - inflections
>
>   - in plural: *die Hunde*
>   - dative plural: *den Hunden*
>   - genitive singular: *des Hunds, des Hundes*
> - pronunciation: *[hʊnt], Plural: [ˈhʊndə]* (audio samples available)
> - hyphenation: *Hund, Plural: Hun·de*

Voilà!