# Looking for ALL german verbs database

Tags: verb, irregular-verb

It could be plain text. I need to have there all verbs with all forms written down.

I'm afraid I can't use any web source, 'cause I want to create an application that will "read" sample german book and make stats about verbs. Which was most frequently used.

Thanks for help!

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/5653/2225 You could parse for verbs.

Comment: I have a pdf book with over `500 verbs` that are `conjugated in all present, perfect, prateritum etc...` But I don't know if the rules of this website allow us to share contact info. If yes, then I can share it with you through some online medium.

Comment: well, it would be great. I think there is nothing wrong when you contact me on now77ak(at)hotmail.com. My email is visible in my profile.. i think. Thanks

Comment: Done. Hope it helps. @Marshall

Comment: Thanks, it looks what I was looking for. I will test it and let u know

Comment: This answer just doesn't make sense. Since the question was left open, it means that we have to provide an answer readable to all of the site, not private comunication.

Comment: There's mecab that does this for Japanese, so I tried googling for a similar program for German: https://github.com/rsennrich/ParZu/ analyzes sentences, the readme contains links to the morphological analyzers zmorge, morphisto and gertwol, which is what you may be looking for. A list with 500 verbs do not seem enough to me, especially if verbs with prefixes (los-gehen, ab-gehen &c.) are counted separately.

Comment: Can there actually exist a list of *all* verbs? I guess the best you can do is a list of verbs which have been used in notable sources. But German has the ability to create verbs from nouns and to create nouns by combining other nouns, therefore the total set of verbs should IMHO be unbounded (although probably no one would ever say things like "donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitänisiseren").

Comment: I am not convinced a list is what you are looking for. Have you looked into methods of part of speech tagging from the field of natural language processing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for comprehensive, parsable table of conjugated German nouns](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/looking-for-comprehensive-parsable-table-of-conjugated-german-nouns)

Comment: Hubert, er will eine Software schreiben, die alle Verben kennt. Da nützt ihm keine Datenbank aller Substantive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:
[List of german verbs](http://www.verblisten.de/)

Comment: did you understand the question? No web source, all verb forms written down.

Comment: Thanks for an answer but as teylyn has written - need some offline source.

Comment: By a printer, some ink and paper

Answer (score 0):

This simply cant exist.

A verb in german is not an element out of a list, it is a process of creation and a rule how to instatiate a concept.

Do you know those verbs?

gleichlauftesten? tiefschockgefrieren? rückenkraulen? kopplungsamplitudenverstärken? einkommenssteuerfreibetragbereinigen?

Comment: If something like this cant exist: What is this: http://www.verblisten.de ? In German language you always have the problem of compound words, but there are algorithms how to split them into atomic words, and those atomic words can easily be listed.

Comment: Question is not "most german verbs" or somethinfg like that, it is ALL german verbs. This is open ended.

Answer (score -2):

If you have android or iOS you can download German Verb Conjugator app.

For Android: [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itipton.germanverbs&hl=en)

For iOS: [Here](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/german-verb-conjugation-trainer/id417027134?mt=8)

and [Here](http://itipton.com/) is the developer site.

Comment: Don't! Just by looking at the website I saw some samples of the app - conjugating "malen" (paint) with "du malest" and "ihr malet". That's absolute BS for modern German. I shudder to think what other errors are lurking within, waiting to trap unwitting users.