# Suche eine umfassende Datenbank aller deutschen Wörter

Tags: resource

Ich suche eine (oder mehrere) Gratisdatenbank(en), die u.a. folgende Daten enthält:

- Wortart
- Wortform
- Bei Verben: Konjugationstabelle
- Bei Adjektiven: Angepasste Versionen
- Synonyme
- Wenn möglich Definitionen

… die Datenbank muss *parsbar* sein, d.h. ich muss sie herunterladen und ohne zusätzliche Programme lesen können. Alternativ wäre auch ein mit einem Online-Wörterbuch sprechendes API brauchbar.

Ähnliche Fragen wurden bereits gestellt ([hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/german-words-database) und [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6683/looking-for-all-german-verbs-database)), die Antworten haben mir aber leider nicht wirklich weitergeholfen, da die Wörterbücher entweder in einer Website eingebettet und für einen Dritten nicht direkt zugänglich waren oder viel zu wenig Daten enthielten (z.B. nur eine Liste von Wörtern).

Hier ist ein Beispiel, wie ich mir das in etwa vorstelle – ein Bild der 1'900 € teuren Datenbank der Website language-databases.com:

Konjugationstabelle:
[image: Konjugationen]
Synonyme:
[image: Synonyme]

In English – I’m searching for a free, comprehensive, parsable database or API of German words.

Comment: Siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words, http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/looking-for-comprehensive-parsable-table-of-conjugated-german-nouns

Comment: Wunderbar. Vielen Dank! Schaue mir das gleich mal an.

Comment: 1900 Euro teure Exceltabellen, da staunste. Hoffe das ist nur ein Export?

Comment: Die Uni Leipzig bietet ihren "Wortschatz" als Datenbank und als Textfile zum herunterladen an. Vielleicht ist das etwas womit du arbeiten kannst: http://corpora2.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/download.html

Answer (score 5):

Du könntest dir das deutsche Wörterbuch von Hunspell herunterladen. Es ist in der Wörterbuch-Extension für OpenOffice enthalten:

http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries

Das Paket ist eine Zip-Datei, die du entpacken und öffnen kannst, wenn du die Erweiterung von .oxt in .zip änderst. Darin enthalten ist im Ordner de_DE_frami die Datei de_DE_frami.dic (ist eine normale Textdatei), die Worte und Wortstämme enthält, allerdings auch Namen wie Personen-, Städte- oder Straßennamen.

Comment: Man kann Zipdateien auch entpacken ohne die Endung zu ändern.

Comment: @userunknown Entpacken direkt aus oxt klappt nur, wenn man die richtigen Programme (z. B. 7-Zip) installiert hat. Wenn man's umbenennt, klappt es auch mit Windows Bordmitteln - was mMn als Voraussetzung bei einer allgemeinen Anleitung im Internet zu bevorzugen ist. :)

Comment: Was ist denn das Bordmittel Windows'?

Comment: Seit Windows XP kann man Zips aus dem Kontextmenü des Exporers entpacken (Alle extrahieren...). Diese Option zeigt das Kontextmenü aber nur für .zip Dateien an, nicht für .zip-artige Dateien. Ob MS den Algorithmus selbst implementiert hat oder eine transparent integrierte Software nutzt (wie auch bei OneDrive) - keine Ahnung. Aber jedenfalls funktioniert es bereits "ab Werk" auf einem frisch installierten System. 7-Zip muss man halt selber installieren, dafür wird dann dessen "Entpacken" Option nicht nur für .zip sondern auch "verkleidete" Archive (wie eben .oxt, .docx, usw.) angeboten.

Comment: Und wie darf ich mir diese Bordmittel vorstellen? Ist das vielleicht ein Programm? Liegt dieses Programm in Form einer Datei vor, oder wie sonst? Und diese Datei kann man nicht von der Kommandozeile aufrufen und eine Zipdatei als Argument übergeben, die nicht den Namen "*zip" hat?

Comment: Gegenfrage - wieso sollte man das tun wollen? Inwiefern würde es die Anleitung verbessern, mit anderen Programmen oder der Kommandozeile zu hantieren? Nur, weil es geht? Erweiterung ändern, doppelt anklicken zum Öffnen. Das ist der Weg, der das niedrigeste Level an sonstigen Kenntnissen voraussetzt. Der Windows Explorer zeigt den Inhalt dann so an, als wäre es ein "ganz normaler" Ordner, mit allen Funktionen, die man kennt.

Comment: Vielleicht, weil man auf einem Rechner arbeiten muss, bei dem man nichts selbst installieren darf.

Answer (score 4):

Die in [JSON geparste Version der deutschen Einträge der englischen Wiktionary](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/German/) ist wahrscheinlich die beste Ressource für so etwas. Enthält alle Daten wie z. B. gebeugte Formen und Kategorien, allerdings nur englische und keine deutschen Definitionen.

Comment: Leider gehen die Links nicht bis zu den Wörtern. Gibt es eine andere Quelle wie diese. Diese JSON Version wäre perfekt, ist aber leider nicht auf Dateiebene aufrufbar.

Comment: @mcflysoft Die Version unter dem Unterschrift "Download" sollte ohne Probleme herunterladbar sein (als einzelne Datei mit allen Infos darin).