# List of 1000+ (most common) German nouns with plural form

Tags: noun, resource, vocabulary

Has anyone managed to find a list of this kind in a tabular form, possibly with articles? Something like this would be ideal:

```
----------------------------
das Kind     |  die Kinder |
der Hund     |  die Hunde  |
das Zimmer   |  die Zimmer |
----------------------------
```

A plain list, just like the one above, would be ideal since I would like to print it. Just an article, noun and plural form. Although there are many lists on the internet, they are mostly up to a 100 words, with word explanations examples, with missing articles etc. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: closely related (though not including the top 1000): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/looking-for-comprehensive-parsable-table-of-conjugated-german-nouns

Comment: Heutiges Deutsch oder über eine längere Epoche? Nur schriftliches oder auch mündliches Deutsch? Wie sollte das ermittelt werden - sollte jeder Text gleich stark gewichtet sein oder häufig gelesenes proportional stärker als selten gelesenes? Soll man hilfsweise verkaufte Exemplare der Schriften wählen?

Comment: -1 for this Aschenputtel task. Please, consider other language learning techniques.

Comment: +1 because one style of learning that doesn't work for you or seems ridiculous to you may be extremely useful for someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=table&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) to an online dictionary that shows what you want, but in a little more complicated form.  For example, type in "table" and it returns:

der Tisch Pl: die Tische

And here is a [list](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913081547/http://www.byki.com/lists/german/greg%27s-german-nouns-part-1.html) someone named "Greg" put together, for his own use, of 1000 nouns.

His format is: das Abitur, -e    school exam

Answer (score 9):

I'm sharing a list of 1000+ German nouns (with English translations and explanatory notes to such translations) that I wrote out from SPIEGEL and other German newspapers. These nouns are some of the more useful ones that I came across in spring of 2014, as I began to read the German press and put together what has now become a Mega Word List with over 19000 words. Here's the [link](https://germanwordlist.wordpress.com/) where the list can be downloaded:

Comment: Much better now - still you need to know that in case your page goes down later we will have to remove your post again. Ideally we are looking for answers that can all be found on our site but this is probably the best you can get for these kind of questions.

Comment: I also wrote my own "Mega" list! I even named it same!

Comment: So I've just downloaded the list and I must say - it is perfect for me to learn English! Thank you for that!

Comment: It has its uses, but it's not quite what OP asked for - he wanted the MOST COMMON words. Your list is from an intellectual newspaper and is full of terms like "validity", "shareholder", etc, but lacks the basics like "water" "table" "basket" etc

Comment: @gotofritz Please notice, however, that "most common" was parenthesized, which usually means the sentence can as well be read without the parenthesized expression. Besides, Danilo Radenovich, the author of the question, indicated, just above your comment, that he is happy with my list.

Comment: Well, I was looking for the most common 1000 nouns too (that's how I ended up here) and I think Greg's list  in the accepted answer is more useful. But thanks for sharing yours.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend that you check out this [ProVoc site](http://www.arizona-software.ch/provoc/vocabulary.html?show=all). You can download entire lists of vocabulary that end-users have compiled. They are free for use, but you need to have OS X (running [Provoc](http://www.arizona-software.ch/provoc/download.html) or [iVocabulary](http://apps.chbeer.de/en/ivocabulary/mac/)) or iOS ([iVocabulary](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ivocabulary-your-flexible/id294531015?mt=8)).

**These files can be exported to CSV lists and then imported in Excel, for example**

Comment: Please note that the PorVoc project has been discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own list, using these two resources:

1. [This extensive morphology database.](http://www.danielnaber.de/morphologie/)
2. [These frequency lists of the most used German words.](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/html/wliste.html)

A little script could filter e.g. the 10000 most frequent word list for nouns and look up the plural form in morphy.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [German Plurals](http://www.germanplurals.com) lookup tool.

You can look up individual words, or paste in a word list of up to 20 words.

You get a table of plurals that you can print.

Not every single word is in their database but most everyday words that I've looked up seem to be in there.

Comment: This isn't exactly a table, but it is a legitimate means of getting the same information.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve copied Greg’s list (mentioned in [Rob’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/12081)) and made it a bit clearer wich nouns are male, female of neutral, by adding color. I might later on add some additional (difficult) words whenever I feel like it. For now [my list](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByXq11DD2gcSaTg1T2lPV3NUVm8&usp=sharing) is 1000 words.

Comment: The link to the list is dead / 404.