# Is there any file or available source for German nouns + definite article

Tags: learning, resource, online-resource

I'm trying to find files or any kind of source for German nouns together with definite article. The goal is to create an app which will use that data and help me with learning.

Comment: There already is a similar question: List of 1000+ (most common) German nouns with plural form. Link: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/list-of-1000-most-common-german-nouns-with-plural-form

Comment: Thanks. I already found this but it's not helpful to me. I'm looking for something huge which will cover almost every word. I'm really not sure if something like that is available..

Comment: I would assume that the Wiktionary data is available in source form.

Comment: @EugeneStr. Vielen Dank! This will be really good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatical gender and definite article in nominative case singular **always** match this way:

- masculine = der
- feminine = die
- neuter = das

Every German dictionary contains either the definite article or a gender-note (m/f/n) for every noun.

Take the most famous dictionary »der Duden« for example:

Let's say, you look for the genders (i.e definite articles) of *Messer, Gabel, Löffel* (knife, fork, spoon):

- Messer:
  http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Messer
  You find:

  > Mes­ser
  >
  > Substantiv, ***Neutrum*** - a. aus einer Klinge, die mit …b. Skalpell; c. mit einer Schneide versehene Leiste …
- Gabel:
  http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Gabel

  > Ga­bel
  >
  > Substantiv, ***feminin*** - 1. Essgerät mit zwei oder mehr …2. Gerät mit zwei oder mehr …3a. Gabelung eines Weges, einer Straße
- Löffel
  [http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Löffel](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/L%C3%B6ffel)

  > Löf­fel
  >
  > Substantiv, ***maskulin*** - 1a. [metallenes] [Ess]gerät, an dessen unterem …1b. Kürette; 2. Ohr von Hase und Kaninchen

From the words that I have marked bold and italics, you can learn:

- Messer = neuter; Article = das (das Messer)
- Gabel = feminin; Article = die (die Gabel)
- Löffel = maskulin; Article = der (der Löffel)

But be aware, that there are also words that can be used in two or even all three genders:

- Gummi (rubber)
  http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Gummi

  > Gum­mi
  >
  > Substantiv, ***maskulin*** oder Substantiv, ***Neutrum*** - 1. durch Vulkanisation aus natürlichem oder …
- Bookmark (bookmark)
  http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/bookmark

  > Book­mark
  >
  > Substantiv, ***Neutrum*** oder Substantiv, ***maskulin*** oder Substantiv, ***feminin*** - Eintrag in einem persönlichen elektronischen Adressenverzeichnis zum schnellen Auffinden von bestimmten Websites

So it is:

- Gummi = masculin or neuter; Article = der, das (der Gummi, das Gummi)
- Bookmark = neuter, masculin or feminin; Article = das, der, die (das Bookmark, der Bookmark, die Bookmark)

In those examples you can choose which article you want to use. Often there are regional preferences (»Das Gummi« in northern parts of Germany, »der Gummi« in southern parts and in Austria).

But there are also homonyms with different articles

- Schild (das Schild = tag, plate, sign, label, ...; der Schild = shield)
  http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Schild

  > Schild
  >
  > Substantiv, ***maskulin*** - 1. eine Schutzwaffe darstellender, auf seiner …2. Wappenschild; 3. schildförmiger, länglicher Schirm an der …
  >
  > ...
  >   Schild
  >
  > Substantiv, ***Neutrum*** - 1. Tafel, Platte mit einem Zeichen, …2. Fleck auf der Brust (besonders …

So here you have:

- Schild = masculin; Article = der (der Schild) (if you mean a shield to protect whatever is behind the shield)
- Schild = neuter; Article = das (das Schild) (if you mean a label, tag, or something similar where you can write a few words that are representative for the thing on which the label/tag/... is mounted)

Comment: What makes you think that the OP is not aware of this?

Comment: @CarstenS: Nothing. Where did I say that the OP was not aware of this? I just told him (and anybody else who reads this answer) to be aware.

Comment: That's cool. I am going to add an answer later that explains what a file is.

Comment: @CarstenS: Fine. Then I will add an addendum to your answer where I explain especially for you what »any kind of source« is.

Comment: This will be great. We will see how much text we can produce without answering the question.

Comment: Well it's my question so let me comment this one as well :) I appreciate this answer because it helped me actually to figure out how to get data I need. It's nothing that I already don't know, but it was a bullet which triggered different approach in my head :) When I finish with my work I'll publish my dataset here so that everyone can use it.So thanks @HubertSchölnast

Comment: @hellwd: Ich you find my answer helpful, you could up-vote it or accept it (only if you want).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I voted for it, but someone also down-voted - I'm not sure why. I can't accept it because it's not answer that solved my problem. The correct answer would be the either file or some resource where I can find what I'm looking for. I find your answer helpful, and thanks for that :)