# Looking for large list of nouns with gender

Tags: noun, gender, resource

I have found several extensive, machine-parsable lists of German words, but none of them give the gender of the nouns.

Can someone point me to a comprehensive list of noun with their gender (or equivalently, with their articles)?

(I tried the file suggested [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5653/1890), but I found it very difficult to extract the information I wanted from that file.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a "Vollformenlexikon" available for download [here.](http://www.danielnaber.de/morphologie/) It doesn't only cover nouns, but they are easily identifiable and extractable from the xml, which also includes gender information for nouns.

Comment: That's a beautifully done piece of work.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

I found a list of 1000 words with gender (as indicated by the der, die and das in the site "[German word list-Greg's German nouns](http://www.byki.com/lists/german/greg%27s-german-nouns-part-1.html)") under Google question for "German nouns list with gender"

Comment: Welcome. You could improve this a lot by adding the link!