# Datenbank mit Artikeln

Tags: translation, resource

Ich suche für diverse Sprachen wie Deutsch, Französisch etc. eine Datenbank, bei der die Artikel mit hinterlegt sind.

**Beispiele:**

- Auto (das)
- maison (la)

Das müsste als Datenbankformat, Textdatei etc. vorhanden sein, damit ich diese über eine Programmiersprache parsen kann.

Comment: Was heißt denn *diverse Sprachen*? Afrikaans auch?

Comment: Derzeit würde mir Englisch, Französisch, Deutsch und Arabisch genügen.

Comment: @Yvon Folz, willkommen bei German.Stackexchange. Bitte ergänze Informationen zu deiner Frage, indem du die Frage editierst (der Edit-Button ist unter der Frage).

Comment: @YvonFolz, Englisch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finding a database.

Comment: Du suchst wahrscheinlich eine Liste von Substantiven mit Genus, nicht
eine Liste von Substantiven mit Artikel. (Der englische Artikel *the* und der arabische Artikel *al*
sagen nämlich nichts über das Genus aus und der französische Artikel
*l'* vor Vokal ebensowenig.)

Comment: Ich halte es für ziemlich überflüssig, eine Datenbank zu führen, in der für jedes englische Substantiv der Artikel angeführt ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Erinnert mich an die nicht wirklich ernst gemeinte englische Übersetzung vom Sesamstraße-Lied (*Der, die, das - wer, wie, was - wieso, weshalb, warum ...*): *The, the, the - Who, how, what - Why, why, why ...*

Comment: Korrekt. Es geht vor um die Artikel in Deutsch, Französisch sowie ob etwas weiblich, männlich, sachlich ist.

Comment: @YvonFolz Französisch wäre aber hier off-topic :-) Wenn man im Deutschen den Artikel kennt, erübrigt sich die Angabe, ob etwas männlich, weiblich oder sächlich ist (oder umgekehrt, je nachdem, welche Info man hat).

Answer (score 5):

Da es Dir wohl vor allem um die Angabe des Genus geht und sich die Frage daher mit [*Looking for large list of nouns with gender*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15696/392) überschneidet, wird Dir wahrscheinlich auch die dortige Antwort Elenas weiterhelfen: sie verweist auf das ganz hervorragende [**Vollformenlexikon** von Daniel Naber](http://www.danielnaber.de/morphologie/), das wiederum aus [Morphy](http://morphy.wolfganglezius.de/download/) generiert wurde. Die XML-Datei enthält zwar nicht nur Nomen, aber man kann sie anhand der XML-Attribute zu Wortart und Genus sehr einfach filtern. Die Einträge sehen folgendermaßen aus:

```
<item>
  <form>Auto</form>
    <lemma wkl="SUB" kas="NOM" num="SIN" gen="NEU">Auto</lemma>
    <lemma wkl="SUB" kas="DAT" num="SIN" gen="NEU">Auto</lemma>
    <lemma wkl="SUB" kas="AKK" num="SIN" gen="NEU">Auto</lemma>
  </item>
<item>
```

Das Vollformenlexikon ist auch in [Daniel Nabers **LanguageTool**](https://www.languagetool.org/) integriert. Dieses Tool enthält außerdem noch **grammatikalisch annotierte Wörterbücher zu einer ganzen Reihe anderer Sprachen**. Man kann diese Wörterbücher relativ einfach [aus der jeweiligen kompilierten Version extrahieren](http://wiki.languagetool.org/developing-a-tagger-dictionary#toc2) (dazu [muss man die languagetool-tools aus den Quellen kompilieren](http://forum.languagetool.org/t/dictionarybuilder-exporter-moved-in-3-3-command-line-options/910), der DictionaryExporter ist entgegen anderslautender Hinweise im LanguageTool-Wiki nicht mehr in der jars der Standalone-Version enthalten). Zwar unterscheidet sich die Syntax zwischen den Sprachen, aber bei den Nomina ist jeweils auch das Genus angegeben. Die Einträge der Dictionaries sehen zB wie folgt aus:

Deutsch:

```
Auto    Auto    SUB:AKK:SIN:NEU
Auto    Auto    SUB:DAT:SIN:NEU
Auto    Auto    SUB:NOM:SIN:NEU
Autos   Auto    SUB:AKK:PLU:NEU
Autos   Auto    SUB:DAT:PLU:NEU
Autos   Auto    SUB:GEN:PLU:NEU
Autos   Auto    SUB:GEN:SIN:NEU
Autos   Auto    SUB:NOM:PLU:NEU
```

Französisch:

```
automobiles automobile  N f p
automobile  automobile  N f s
```

<sup>Anmerkung: Nicht alle Wörterbücher des LanguageTool stehen unter der GPL - daher bitte unbedingt die Lizenzinformationen beachten!</sup>

Eine dritte Möglichkeit wären die **Dumps der verschiedenen Wiktionaries**; z.B. kann man über die Seite https://dumps.wikimedia.org/dewiktionary/20160601/ den aktuellen Dump des [de-Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) herunterladen. Weitere Dumps findet man am einfachsten über die [Download-Einstiegsseite der Wikimedia Foundation](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/). Die einzelnen Einträge sind aber sehr umfangreich, und für die Ermittlung des Genus müsste man den [Wikitext](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikitext)-Quellcode parsen:

```
<page>
    <title>Auto</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1147</id>
    <revision>
      <id>4965206</id>
      <parentid>4883913</parentid>
      <timestamp>2016-05-24T19:13:29Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Dr. Karl-Heinz Best</username>
        <id>5327</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>+ unterbegr</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">{{Siehe auch|[[auto-]], [[auto]]}}
== Auto ({{Sprache|Deutsch}}) ==
=== {{Wortart|Substantiv|Deutsch}}, {{n}} ===

{{Deutsch Substantiv Übersicht
|Genus=n
|Nominativ Singular=Auto
|Nominativ Plural=Autos
|Genitiv Singular=Autos
|Genitiv Plural=Autos
|Dativ Singular=Auto
|Dativ Plural=Autos
|Akkusativ Singular=Auto
|Akkusativ Plural=Autos
|Bild=Scarsdale Concours Enzo 2.jpg|mini|1|''Auto'' am Beispiel eines Ferrari Enzo
}}

{{Worttrennung}}
:Au·to, {{Pl.}} Au·tos

{{Aussprache}}
:{{IPA}} {{Lautschrift|ˈaʊ̯to}}
:{{Hörbeispiele}} {{Audio|De-Auto.ogg|Auto}}, {{Audio|De-at-Auto.ogg|Auto (österreichisch)}}

{{Bedeutungen}}
:[1] {{K|Verkehr}} selbst [[angetrieben]]es [[Straßenfahrzeug]]; mehr noch als in der Langform [[Automobil]] sind hier meist [[Personenkraftwagen]] gemeint
:[2] {{K|Spiel}} [[Spielzeug]] oder kleines [[Fahrzeug]] für [[Kinder]], das wie &lt;sup&gt;[1]&lt;/sup&gt; aussieht

{{Herkunft}}
:im frühen 20. Jahrhundert entstandene Kurzform des [[Kompositum]]s ''Automobil'', das mit dem Präfix ''[[auto-]]'' „selbst-“ aus dem Griechischen gebildet wurde &lt;ref&gt;{{Ref-DWDS|Auto}}&lt;/ref&gt;

{{Synonyme}}
:[1] [[Automobil]], [[PKW]], [[Personenkraftwagen]], [[Wagen]]
:[2] [[Spielzeugauto]]

{{Oberbegriffe}}
:[1] [[Kraftfahrzeug]], [[Kraftwagen]], [[Verkehrsmittel]]

{{Unterbegriffe}}
:[1] [[Dreiliterauto]], [[Drittauto]], [[Geländeauto]], [[Jahresauto]], [[Kompaktauto]], [[Lieblingsauto]], [[Luxusauto]], [[Montagsauto]], [[Mikroauto]], [[Miniauto]], [[Modellauto]], [[Nanoauto]], [[Nanotruck]], [[Raketenauto]], [[Roboterauto]], [[Schrottauto]], [[Serienauto]], [[Sparauto]], [[SUB-A-Auto]], [[Traumauto]], [[Unfallauto]], [[Vorjahresauto]], [[Weltauto]], [[Wunschauto]], [[Zweitauto]]
:[1] ''nach Antrieb:'' [[Brennstoffzellenauto]], [[Elektroauto]], [[Erdgasauto]], [[Hybridauto]], [[Solarauto]], [[Tretauto]], [[Verbrennungsauto]], [[Wasserstoffauto]]
:[1] ''nach Einsatz:'' [[Feuerwehrauto]], [[Firmenauto]], [[Fluchtauto]], [[Lieferwagen]], [[Lastauto]], [[Mietauto]], [[Milchauto]], [[Mondauto]], [[Müllauto]], [[Polizeiauto]], [[Postauto]], [[Privatauto]], [[Rennauto]], [[Sanitätsauto]]
:[1] ''nach Modell:'' [[Cabrio]], [[Coupé]], [[Kombi]], [[Limousine]], [[Roadster]]  [[Straßenkreuzer]], [[SUV]], [[Van]]
:[1] ''nach Verwender:'' [[Frauenauto]], [[Siegerauto]], [[Spaßauto]], [[Stadtauto]]
:[1, 2] [[Blechauto]], [[Holzauto]], [[Kunststoffauto]], [[Plastikauto]]

{{Beispiele}}
:[1] Ich fahre mit dem ''Auto'' nach Italien.
:[1] Ich habe gar kein ''Auto.''
:[1] Kannst du ''Auto'' fahren?
:[1] Er hat sich ein gebrauchtes ''Auto'' gekauft.
:[1] „Sie spazierten am Rathaus vorbei, bergan, bis sie eine Straße erreicht hatten, auf der sich ''Autos'' und Autobusse hupend ihren Weg bahnten.“&lt;ref&gt;{{Literatur|Autor=Erich Kästner|Titel=Der Zauberlehrling|TitelErg=Ein Fragment|Sammelwerk=Kästner für Erwachsene 3|Verlag=Deutscher Bücherbund|Ort=Stuttgart/München|Jahr=|Seiten=203–297, Zitat Seite 224|ISBN=}}, entstanden 1936.&lt;/ref&gt;
:[2] Unsere Tochter spielt gerne mit ''Autos.''

{{Redewendungen}}
:[1] [[wie ein Auto gucken]]

{{Charakteristische Wortkombinationen}}
:[1] ''Auto'' [[fahren]], {{Audio|De-riskant Auto fahren.ogg|-&gt;}} [[riskant]] ''Auto'' [[fahren]], [[sicher]] ''Auto'' [[fahren]]
:[2] [[mit]] ''Autos'' [[spielen]]

{{Wortbildungen}}
:{{Wortbildung|Adjektive}} [[autofeindlich]], [[autofrei]], [[autofreundlich]]
:{{Wortbildung|Substantive}} [[Autoabgase]], [[Autoaufkleber]], [[Autobahn]], [[Autobatterie]], [[Autobesitzer]], [[Autobewertung]],[[Autobombe]], [[Autobranche]], [[Autobus]], [[Autodieb]], [[Autodiebstahl]], [[Autodroschke]], [[Autofasten]], [[Autofenster]], [[Autofahrer]], [[Autofähre]], [[Autofahrt]], [[Autofriedhof]], [[Autohandel]], [[Autohaus]], [[Autohändler]], [[Autohersteller]],  [[Autoherstellung]], [[Autohof]], [[Autoindustrie]], [[Autokarte]], [[Autokauf]], [[Autokäufer]], [[Autokino]],[[Autoklimaanlage]], [[Autoknacker]], [[Autokolonne]], [[Autokonzern]], [[Autokorso]], [[Autolautsprecher]], [[Automafia]], [[Automarke]], [[Automarkt]], [[Automat]], [[Automatik]], [[Automatikgetriebe]], [[Automechaniker]], [[Automobil]], [[Automodell]], [[Automotor]], [[Autopanne]], [[Autoput]], [[Autoradio]], [[Autorennen]], [[Autoreifen]], [[Autoschlange]], [[Autoschlosser]], [[Autounfall]], [[Autoverkehr]], [[Autoverwerter]], [[Autoverleih]], [[Autovermieter]], [[Autovermietung]], [[Autoversicherer]], [[Autoversicherung]], [[Autowaschanlage]], [[Autowerkstatt]], [[Autowrack]], [[Autozubehör]], [[Autozug]], [[Autozulieferer]]

==== Übersetzungen ====
{{Ü-Tabelle|Ü-links=
*{{sq}}: [1] {{Ü|sq|makinë}}
*{{ar}}: [1] {{Üxx5|ar|sajja:ra(tun)|‏سَيَّارَة|‏سيارة}} {{f}}
*{{az}}: [1] {{Ü|az|avtomobil}}
*{{bg}}: [1] {{Üt|bg|кола|kolá}} {{f}}
*{{zh}}:
**{{zh-tw}}: [1] {{Üt|zh|汽車|qìchē}}
**{{zh-cn}}: [1] {{Üt|zh|汽车|qìchē}}
*{{da}}: [1] {{Ü|da|bil}}
*{{en}}: [1] {{Ü|en|auto}}, {{Ü|en|car}}, {{Ü|en|motor car}}
*{{eo}}: [1] {{Ü|eo|aŭtomobilo}}, {{Ü|eo|aŭto}}
*{{fo}}: [1] {{Ü|fo|bilur}}
*{{fi}}: [1] {{Ü|fi|auto}}
*{{fr}}: [1] {{Ü|fr|auto}}, {{Ü|fr|automobile}}, {{Ü|fr|voiture}}
*{{ka}}: [1] {{Üt|ka|ავტომანქანა|avt'omankana}}, {{Üt|ka|ავტომობილი|avt'omobili}}
*[[Neugriechisch|Griechisch]]: [1] {{Üt|el|αυτοκίνητο|aftokínito}}
*{{he}}: [1] {{Üt|he|מכונית|mexonit}}
*{{io}}: [1] {{Ü|io|automobilo}}
*{{ga}}: [1] {{Ü|ga|carr}}
*{{is}}: [1] {{Ü|is|bíll}}, {{Ü|is|bifreið}}, {{Ü|is|vagn}}
*{{it}}: [1] {{Ü|it|automobile}} {{f}}, {{Ü|it|auto}} {{f}}, {{Ü|it|macchina}} {{f}}
*{{ja}}: [1] {{Üt|ja|自動車|じどうしゃ, jidōsha}} ; {{Üt|ja|車|くるま, kuruma}}
*{{yi}}: [1] {{Üt|yi|אויטאָ|YIVO-Transkription: oyto}}
*{{ca}}: [1] {{Ü|ca|cotxe}} {{m}}, {{Ü|ca|auto}} {{m}}, {{Ü|ca|automòbil}} {{m}}
|Ü-rechts=
*{{ko}}: [1] {{Üt|ko|차|cha}} ''(Fahrzeug, kann in PKW, LKW spezialisiert werden)''
*{{la}}: [1] {{Ü|la|autocinetum}} {{n}}, {{Ü|la|autoraeda}} {{f}}
*{{lt}}: [1] {{Ü|lt|automobilis}}
*{{nds}}: [1] {{Ü|nds|Auto}}, {{Ü|nds|Karr}}
*{{nl}}: [1] {{Ü|nl|auto}}
*{{no}}: [1] {{Ü|no|bil}} {{m}}
*{{oc}}: [1] {{Ü|oc|veitura}} {{f}}, {{Ü|oc|carri}}
*{{pl}}: [1] {{Ü|pl|samochód}} {{m}}, {{Ü|pl|auto}} {{n}}, [2] {{Ü|pl|samochodzik}} {{m}}
*{{pt}}: [1] {{Ü|pt|automóvel}}, {{Ü|pt|carro}}
*{{ro}}: [1] {{Ü|ro|automobil}} {{n}}, {{Ü|ro|mașină}} {{f}}
*{{ru}}: [1] {{Üt|ru|автомобиль|avtomobíl'}} {{m}}, {{Üt|ru|машина|mašína}} {{f}}; [2] {{Üt|ru|машинка|mašínka}} {{f}}
*{{sv}}: [1] {{Ü|sv|bil}} {{u}}
*{{sr}}: [1] {{Üt|sr|аутомобил|automobil}}, {{Üt|sr|ауто|auto}}, {{Üt|sr|кола|kola}}, {{Üt|sr|машина|maʂina}}
*{{sk}}: [1] {{Ü|sk|auto}} {{n}}, [2] {{Ü|sk|autíčko}} {{n}}
*{{wen}}:
**{{dsb}}: [1] {{Ü|dsb|awto}} {{n}}
**{{hsb}}: [1] {{Ü|hsb|awto}} {{n}}
*{{es}}: [1] {{Ü|es|automóvil}} {{m}}, {{Ü|es|coche}} {{m}}, {{Ü|es|auto}} {{m}}, {{Ü|es|carro}} {{m}}
*{{sw}}: [1] {{Ü|sw|gari}}
*{{cs}}: [1] {{Ü|cs|auto}} {{n}}
*{{tr}}: [1] {{Ü|tr|oto}}
*{{hu}}: [1] {{Ü|hu|autó}}, {{Ü|hu|kocsi}}
*{{cy}}: [1] {{Ü|cy|car}} {{m}}
}}

{{Referenzen}}
:[1] {{Wikipedia}}
:[1] {{Ref-DWDS}}
:[1] {{Ref-Canoo}}
:[1] {{Ref-UniLeipzig}}
:[1] {{Ref-FreeDictionary}}
:[1, 2] {{Ref-Duden|Auto_Automobil|Auto}}

{{Quellen}}

{{Ähnlichkeiten 1|[[Autor]]}}

[[Kategorie:Fremdwort]]

[[ar:Auto]]
[[bs:Auto]]
[[ca:Auto]]
[[chr:Auto]]
[[cs:Auto]]
[[da:Auto]]
[[el:Auto]]
[[en:Auto]]
[[et:Auto]]
[[eu:Auto]]
[[fi:Auto]]
[[fj:Auto]]
[[fr:Auto]]
[[fy:Auto]]
[[ga:Auto]]
[[hu:Auto]]
[[id:Auto]]
[[io:Auto]]
[[is:Auto]]
[[it:Auto]]
[[ja:Auto]]
[[ka:Auto]]
[[kn:Auto]]
[[ko:Auto]]
[[ku:Auto]]
[[kw:Auto]]
[[li:Auto]]
[[lt:Auto]]
[[mg:Auto]]
[[nah:Auto]]
[[nds:Auto]]
[[nl:Auto]]
[[no:Auto]]
[[pl:Auto]]
[[pt:Auto]]
[[ru:Auto]]
[[sk:Auto]]
[[sv:Auto]]
[[th:Auto]]
[[tl:Auto]]
[[tr:Auto]]
[[zh:Auto]]</text>
      <sha1>ll1mfi4r5ohyir6u1qasyxytg08sllb</sha1>
    </revision>
  </page>
```

Comment: Vielen vielen Dank!

Comment: MediaWiki benutzt _nicht MarkDown_, sondern eine eigene Markupsprache.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Uuups - richtig, habbich korrigiert.... Danke für den Hinweis!